# How can I reduce the length and intensity of SMS notification vibrations?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, sms, vibration

After upgrading my Galaxy GT-i9000 to Gingerbread, the vibration when receiving an SMS is unbelievably long and hard. Before the upgrade (2.1?), the vibration was two short vibrations. How can I customize the vibrations, or get the "normal" vibration? This long vibration is not pleasant.

P.S. The vibration intensity config is only applied for the vibration when hitting a button, not for receiving SMS.

P.S. 2: And the camera is extremly slow when taking picture..it is focusing everytime, and it takes 2-3 seconds to take a photo. Before the upgrade it took like millisecond:/

Comment: Ask your camera question separately, please.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to disable the notfications from the built-in messaging app (in the Messaging app, press <kbd>Menu</kbd>, select *Settings* and then scroll to the bottom and take the tick out of the *Notifications* box).

You can then use a 3rd party app that gives you full customization of the notification options, like [SMS Popup](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.everythingandroid.smspopup) which gives you control over the vibration duration and pattern, as well as a lot of other notification options.

Comment: thanks. i have sort of "fixed" the camera. Downloaded an app that cam take out the autofocus and i can snap a picture anywhere on the screen.

Though incomming calls is very annoying, because lots of calls i cannot answer :S

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you use androids default SMS app. Open it, go to settings -> notification settings -> vibrate pattern. If you are using a specific SMS app, setting this up might be similar (if the app supports it).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i dont got any vibrate pattern setting in the default sms app im afraid:/